# Postfix DNS problem

Tags: dns, postfix, home-server

So i get interesting problem with postfix which is it cannot sent emails with its own SMTP service! I need to use third party smtp server which is bad option. That error log is at friendpaste:  [Mail log](https://friendpaste.com/5gFQw9wPBFOgNjue640Zym) (If it ask pass look litle down)

> (It require pass which is Saatana537)

So what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems network related, not postfix related.
If zou can ping servers like mx47488.pri.secmail.com .
then you shoud look to your routing table, if everything is okay.

Comment: Okey i tryed to ping it but it was unsussecc so how to see my routing table? (And how to see if there is something to fix?)

Comment: the command is simply route. If this takes to long, try route -n

Comment: @user64664 Okey,result is in pastebin: http://pastebin.com/mMrxMvMz

Comment: Yes looks okay. maybe the problem is on the DD-WRT router. what shows traceroute "host.domain" show? try to compare the results from the postfix server with a different machine in you lan.

Comment: There is just that problem that i cannot test it with another machine i only have this and Phone (Can i test with Phone?) If it matters Phone is Iphone 4 (Jailbroked) and that traceroute result is in pastebin: http://pastebin.com/T8D9PqWe